# Rails: association build with index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my edit action I do something like this

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  applications = @user.applications
  if !applications.where(general1: true).present?
    @user.applications.build
  end
  if !applications.where(general2: true).present?
    @user.applications.build
  end
end
```

Now is there any way to specify the index of the build, so that I can do something like this

```
  if !applications.where(general1: true).present?
    @user.applications.build(index: 2)
  end
  if !applications.where(general2: true).present?
    @user.applications.build(index: 1)
  end
```

So basically I want to specify build index of the nested form.

Comment: instead of `@user.applications.build(index: 1)` or `...(index: 2)` can you just name each build: `@build1 = @user.applications.build`, `@build2 = @user.applications.build` and so on? Then use `@build1` and `@build2` in your view?

Comment: It will work but doesn't seems so neat though.